# LogStash - Parse http filter result

Tags: logstash

As always, official doc lacks of examples.

I have a filter that calls an API and has to adds fields parsing the API result:

```
http {
            url => "rest/api/subnet/check_subnet_from_ip/"
            query =>  { "ip" => "%{[source][ip]}" }
            verb => GET
      }
```

API response is something like this:

```
{ "name": "SUBNET1", "cidr": "192.168.0.0/24" }
```

I need to add new fields with these results.
I need to consider an empty result {}

I cant find any example about parsing the results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your response is a `json` document, you need to use the `json` filter to parse it, look at the documentation of the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) for all the options available.

But basically you will need something like this:

```
http {
    url => "rest/api/subnet/check_subnet_from_ip/"
    query =>  { "ip" => "%{[source][ip]}" }
    verb => GET
    target_body => api_response
}
json {
    source => "api_response"
}
```

To add new fields you need to use the `mutate` filter, look at the documentation of the [mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) for all options available.

To add a new field you need something like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "newFieldName" => "newFieldValue" }
}
```

Or to add a new field with the value from an existing field:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "newFieldName" => "%{existingField}" }
}
```

Considering an answer in the format:

```
{ "name": "SUBNET1", "cidr": "192.168.0.0/24" }
```

And the fact that you need to check for empty responses, you will also need to add conditionals, so your pipeline should be something like this example:

```
http {
    url => "rest/api/subnet/check_subnet_from_ip/"
    query =>  { "ip" => "%{[source][ip]}" }
    verb => GET
    target_body => api_response
}
json {
    source => "api_response"
}

if [api_response][name]
{
    mutate 
    {
        add_field => { "[source][subnet][name]" => "%{[api_response][name]}" }
    }
}

if [api_response][cidr]
{
    mutate 
    {
        add_field => { "[source][subnet][cidr]" => "%{[api_response][cidr]}" }
    }
}
```

This will check if the fields `name` and `cidr` exists, and if it exists it will add new fields.

You can also rename the fields if you want, just use this `mutate` configuration instead.

```
mutate {
    rename => { "name" => "subnet_name" }
}
```

Comment: So I can put json inside http filter? Is that "message" word reserved word that Logstash use to refer to https response?

Comment: No, it is another filter just after the http filter. The `message` is just an example, it is a field name. Since you are using hte `http` filter without specifying a [`target_body`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html#plugins-filters-http-target_body), the response will be saved in a field named `body`, so this is the source of your `json` filter.

Comment: So i have:
`filter { 
  http {
            url => "rest/api/subnet/check_subnet_from_ip/"
            query =>  { "ip" => "%{[source][ip]}" }
            verb => GET
            target_body = "api_response"
      }
json {
   source = "api_response"
   mutate {
      add_field => { "subnet_name" : "name" }
      add_field => { "subnet_cidr" : "cidr" }
   }
}
}`

Comment: Thank you. I have just added a fix but now it works. Unfortunally on production env I have to use certificate to make the calls thats seems non working. Is there a way to print a log of the call so I can found out the error?

Comment: Maybe if you change the log level of the logger `logstash.filters.http` to debug [[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html#logging)]. If your http endpoint is local and you are using custom certificates, you will need to add the cacert file path to the http filter, as specified in the documentation. I would suggest that you try that and open another question if this does not work.